# IBM MQ generate key repository for domain user (MQRC_SSL_INITIALIZATION_ERROR)

Tags: asp.net, iis-7.5, ibm-mq, network-service

I have problem with setup key repository configuration for domain user. I have changed the label for *ibmwebspheremqUSERNAME (all in lower case). And it works perfectly for Network Service with the following *ibmwebspheremqnetworkservice. But for domain user I cannot figure out how should I write username. I have tried fllowing:
*ibmwebspheremq**username**
*ibmwebspheremq**domain\username**
*ibmwebspheremq**username@domain.local**

But I got always MQRC_SSL_INITIALIZATION_ERROR when using domain user. Of course ApplicationPool is working on domain user.

Comment: Please update you question to include the error message from the client AMQERR01.LOG file.

Comment: I got "." in username. Do you think this might couse the error? I changed User.Name for UserName and it started to work. I still trying to investigate if this was the reason.

Comment: If you put a character into the user name that isn't part of the user name that will certainly stop it from working.